# C/C++ Library for HFS+ volumes

Tags: open-source, library, osx, c++, c

Any help to find a library which allows reading files containing HFS+ volumes extracted from DMG?

- It could work on raw data, not exactly on DMG files.
- Read-only-mode is enough because one thing which is important for me is getting the ExtentDescriptors for files and their names.
- Platform Windows or Linux, I understand I could mount it on Linux and read directly but it is not what I am interested in because at the end it is supposed to compile on all platforms.
- Language C/C++

I have search through GitHub repositories but I could not find anything sufficient.